# Breaking a string along whitespace once certain width is exceeded (Python)

Tags: python, word-wrap

I am rendering text atop a base image.

One core requirement is for the string to wrap to the next line(s) whenever the total width of characters exceeds the width of the base image. I accomplish this via the following correctly-working snippet:

```
base_width, base_height = base_img.size
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf", font_size)
line_width = 0
line_count = 1
lines = []
string = ""
for c in text:
    line_width += font.getsize(c)[0]
    string+=str(c)
    if line_width > base_width:
        lines.append(string)
        string = ""
        line_width = 0
        line_count += 1
if string:
    lines.append(string)
```

The result `lines` is a list of substrings gotten via breaking up the original string.

Now I need to improve this algorithm.

The problem is that it breaks the line *mid-word*. E.g. The string `lorem ipsum` could end up as `lines = ['lorem ip','sum']`. Instead, the ideal break-up for me is the much more human readable `lines = ['lorem ','ipsum']`, or `lines = ['lorem',' ipsum']`.

In other words, I want to break the lines along white spaces, and not mid-word. Can someone give me an illustrative example of how I can accomplish that? Can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Find the rightmost whitespace in your string, remove the remaining characters, update your counters, writer the result and then start over on the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt to get your code working with minimal changes, and lots of debug output:

```
#!python3
#coding=utf-8
""" Line break demo 2 """

text = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah"

for wmax in [10,25,55,80,100,120]:

    print(wmax)

    base_width, base_height = (wmax,None)#base_img.size
    #font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf", font_size)
    line_width = 0
    line_count = 1
    lines = []
    string = ""
    for c in text:
        line_width += 5#font.getsize(c)[0]
        string += c
        if line_width > base_width:

            print("text  ", text)
            print("string", string)

            s = string.rsplit(" ", 1)
            print("split ", s)

            string = s[0]
            lines.append(string)

            try:
                string = s[1]
                line_width = len(string) * 5
            except:
                string = ""
                line_width = 0

            print("lines ", lines)
            print("string", string)

            line_count += 1
            print()

    if string:
        lines.append(string)


    print(lines)
    print()
```

Output:

```
10
text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string lor
split  ['lor']
lines  ['lor']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string em
split  ['em', '']
lines  ['lor', 'em']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string ips
split  ['ips']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string um
split  ['um', '']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string dol
split  ['dol']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'dol']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string or
split  ['or', '']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'dol', 'or']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string sit
split  ['sit']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'dol', 'or', 'sit']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string  am
split  ['', 'am']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'dol', 'or', 'sit', '']
string am

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string ame
split  ['ame']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'dol', 'or', 'sit', '', 'ame']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string t b
split  ['t', 'b']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'dol', 'or', 'sit', '', 'ame', 't']
string b

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string bla
split  ['bla']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'dol', 'or', 'sit', '', 'ame', 't', 'bla']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string bla
split  ['bla']
lines  ['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'dol', 'or', 'sit', '', 'ame', 't', 'bla', 'bla
string

['lor', 'em', 'ips', 'um', 'dol', 'or', 'sit', '', 'ame', 't', 'bla', 'bla', 'h']

25
text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string lorem
split  ['lorem', '']
lines  ['lorem']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string ipsum
split  ['ipsum', '']
lines  ['lorem', 'ipsum']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string dolor
split  ['dolor', '']
lines  ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string sit am
split  ['sit', 'am']
lines  ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit']
string am

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string amet b
split  ['amet', 'b']
lines  ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet']
string b

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string blabla
split  ['blabla']
lines  ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'blabla']
string

['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'blabla', 'h']

55
text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string lorem ipsum
split  ['lorem ipsum', '']
lines  ['lorem ipsum']
string

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string dolor sit am
split  ['dolor sit', 'am']
lines  ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit']
string am

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string amet blablah
split  ['amet', 'blablah']
lines  ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit', 'amet']
string blablah

['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit', 'amet', 'blablah']

80
text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string lorem ipsum dolor
split  ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor']
lines  ['lorem ipsum']
string dolor

text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string dolor sit amet bl
split  ['dolor sit amet', 'bl']
lines  ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit amet']
string bl

['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit amet', 'blablah']

100
text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string lorem ipsum dolor sit
split  ['lorem ipsum dolor', 'sit']
lines  ['lorem ipsum dolor']
string sit

['lorem ipsum dolor', 'sit amet blablah']

120
text   lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
string lorem ipsum dolor sit ame
split  ['lorem ipsum dolor sit', 'ame']
lines  ['lorem ipsum dolor sit']
string ame

['lorem ipsum dolor sit', 'amet blablah']
```

Comment: I've written one too, I'll add it here. Would be great to get your critique on that!

Comment: Seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a python module [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) specifically for this:

```
In [1]: import textwrap

In [2]: textwrap.wrap('x lorem ipsum', width=5)
Out[2]: ['x', 'lorem', 'ipsum']
```

**edit**:

I misunderstood the author's purpose. The problem is that the width of a line is not defined as the number of characters but as the width of the image containing the rendered text. I came up with a hacky method by implementing a custom string class with correct width definition and modifying the `TextWrapper` class slightly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import textwrap

class MyTextWrapper(textwrap.TextWrapper):

    def _split(self, text):
        assert isinstance(text, StringWithWidth)
        return [StringWithWidth(i) for i in super()._split(text._str)]

    def _wrap_chunks(self, chunks):
        # only modify ''.join in the original code
        """_wrap_chunks(chunks : [string]) -> [string]

        Wrap a sequence of text chunks and return a list of lines of
        length 'self.width' or less.  (If 'break_long_words' is false,
        some lines may be longer than this.)  Chunks correspond roughly
        to words and the whitespace between them: each chunk is
        indivisible (modulo 'break_long_words'), but a line break can
        come between any two chunks.  Chunks should not have internal
        whitespace; ie. a chunk is either all whitespace or a "word".
        Whitespace chunks will be removed from the beginning and end of
        lines, but apart from that whitespace is preserved.
        """
        lines = []
        if self.width <= 0:
            raise ValueError("invalid width %r (must be > 0)" % self.width)
        if self.max_lines is not None:
            if self.max_lines > 1:
                indent = self.subsequent_indent
            else:
                indent = self.initial_indent
            if len(indent) + len(self.placeholder.lstrip()) > self.width:
                raise ValueError("placeholder too large for max width")

        # Arrange in reverse order so items can be efficiently popped
        # from a stack of chucks.
        chunks.reverse()

        while chunks:

            # Start the list of chunks that will make up the current line.
            # cur_len is just the length of all the chunks in cur_line.
            cur_line = []
            cur_len = 0

            # Figure out which static string will prefix this line.
            if lines:
                indent = self.subsequent_indent
            else:
                indent = self.initial_indent

            # Maximum width for this line.
            width = self.width - len(indent)

            # First chunk on line is whitespace -- drop it, unless this
            # is the very beginning of the text (ie. no lines started yet).
            if self.drop_whitespace and chunks[-1].strip() == '' and lines:
                del chunks[-1]

            while chunks:
                l = len(chunks[-1])

                # Can at least squeeze this chunk onto the current line.
                if cur_len + l <= width:
                    cur_line.append(chunks.pop())
                    cur_len += l

                # Nope, this line is full.
                else:
                    break

            # The current line is full, and the next chunk is too big to
            # fit on *any* line (not just this one).
            if chunks and len(chunks[-1]) > width:
                self._handle_long_word(chunks, cur_line, cur_len, width)
                cur_len = sum(map(len, cur_line))

            # If the last chunk on this line is all whitespace, drop it.
            if self.drop_whitespace and cur_line and cur_line[-1].strip() == '':
                cur_len -= len(cur_line[-1])
                del cur_line[-1]

            if cur_line:
                if (self.max_lines is None or
                    len(lines) + 1 < self.max_lines or
                    (not chunks or
                     self.drop_whitespace and
                     len(chunks) == 1 and
                     not chunks[0].strip()) and cur_len <= width):
                    # Convert current line back to a string and store it in
                    # list of all lines (return value).
                    lines.append(StringWithWidth(
                        indent + ''.join(map(_as_str, cur_line))))
                else:
                    while cur_line:
                        if (cur_line[-1].strip() and
                            cur_len + len(self.placeholder) <= width):
                            cur_line.append(self.placeholder)
                            lines.append(StringWithWidth(
                                indent + ''.join(map(_as_str, cur_line))))
                            break
                        cur_len -= len(cur_line[-1])
                        del cur_line[-1]
                    else:
                        if lines:
                            prev_line = lines[-1].rstrip()
                            if (len(prev_line) + len(self.placeholder) <=
                                    self.width):
                                lines[-1] = prev_line + self.placeholder
                                break
                        lines.append(indent + self.placeholder.lstrip())
                    break

        return lines

def _make_str_fwd(name):
    def func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return StringWithWidth(getattr(self._str, name)(*args, **kwargs))
    func.__name__ = name
    return func

def _as_str(val):
    if isinstance(val, StringWithWidth):
        val = val._str
    assert isinstance(val, str)
    return val

class StringWithWidth:
    char_width = {
        'x': 1,
        's': 2,
        ' ': 1
    }

    def __init__(self, s):
        self._str = s

    expandtabs = _make_str_fwd('expandtabs')
    translate = _make_str_fwd('translate')
    strip = _make_str_fwd('strip')
    __getitem__ = _make_str_fwd('__getitem__')

    def __eq__(self, rhs):
        return self._str == _as_str(rhs)

    def __add__(self, rhs):
        return StringWithWidth(self._str + _as_str(rhs))

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(map(self.char_width.__getitem__, self._str))

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._str)


def main():
    print(MyTextWrapper(width=8).wrap(StringWithWidth('x ss s')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Already know about that. It's problem is it doesn't meet my core requirement given one has to pre-fix `width`. Notice how in my case, the width is a variable one cannot prefix beforehand. I actually documented a comprehensive question about that a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43827756/4936905

Comment: @HassanBaig sorry I missed your point, but I think a solution might be possible by using a customized `str` that has its `len` defined to the actual font width, and doing a little extra hack. I am trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this simple approach helps, although I assume recursion may be more elegant. Note that the fixed value for character width needs to be replaced with the corresponding function call.

```py
#!python3
#coding=utf-8
""" Line break demo """

text = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah"
print("breaking", text)

words = text.split()
widths = [sum( [5 for c in w] ) for w in words]
#print(words)
#print(widths)
print(len(words), "words")


for wmax in [10,25,55,80,100,120]:

    print("\nmax line width:", wmax)
    lines = []
    li = 0
    r = range(len(widths))  # 0...5
    for i in r:
        w = sum(widths[li:i+1])
        if w >= wmax and i>0:
            lines.append( " ".join(words[li:i]) )
            li = i
            print("    ---")
            w = sum(widths[li:i+1])

        print( "  ", i, words[i], widths[i], w )
    # remainder
    lines.append( " ".join(words[li:]) )

    print(lines)
```

Output:

```
breaking lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah
6 words

max line width: 10
   0 lorem 25 25
    ---
   1 ipsum 25 25
    ---
   2 dolor 25 25
    ---
   3 sit 15 15
    ---
   4 amet 20 20
    ---
   5 blablah 35 35
['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'blablah']

max line width: 25
   0 lorem 25 25
    ---
   1 ipsum 25 25
    ---
   2 dolor 25 25
    ---
   3 sit 15 15
    ---
   4 amet 20 20
    ---
   5 blablah 35 35
['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'blablah']

max line width: 55
   0 lorem 25 25
   1 ipsum 25 50
    ---
   2 dolor 25 25
   3 sit 15 40
    ---
   4 amet 20 20
    ---
   5 blablah 35 35
['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit', 'amet', 'blablah']

max line width: 80
   0 lorem 25 25
   1 ipsum 25 50
   2 dolor 25 75
    ---
   3 sit 15 15
   4 amet 20 35
   5 blablah 35 70
['lorem ipsum dolor', 'sit amet blablah']

max line width: 100
   0 lorem 25 25
   1 ipsum 25 50
   2 dolor 25 75
   3 sit 15 90
    ---
   4 amet 20 20
   5 blablah 35 55
['lorem ipsum dolor sit', 'amet blablah']

max line width: 120
   0 lorem 25 25
   1 ipsum 25 50
   2 dolor 25 75
   3 sit 15 90
   4 amet 20 110
    ---
   5 blablah 35 35
['lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'blablah']
```

Comment: Instead of `5`, would using `font.getsize(c)[0]` be more precise?

Comment: Yes of course, this needs the function for the actual character width (which I do not have). I have already added a note about that. But I think your code does not need many additions to get working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've approached the problem's solution (re-wrote my original code):

```
def break_lines(img, text, font_size):
    base_width = img.size[0]
    font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf", font_size)
    line = ""
    lines = []
    width_of_line = 0
    number_of_lines = 0
    # break string into multi-lines that fit base_width
    for token in text.split():
        token = token+' '
        token_width = font.getsize(token)[0]
        if width_of_line+token_width < base_width:
            line+=token
            width_of_line+=token_width
        else:
            lines.append(line)
            number_of_lines += 1
            width_of_line = 0
            line = ""
            line+=token
            width_of_line+=token_width
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
        number_of_lines += 1
    return lines, number_of_lines
```

Comment: I think you can omit `filter`ing [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and also you don't need to `str()`what's already a string..

Comment: See the second paragraph of the documentation. Special case with no argument to split on whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this out of my head, so here it is a little more compact:

```
#!python3
#coding=utf-8
""" Line break demo 3 """

def charwidth(char):
    return 5

def stringwidth(string):
    return sum( [charwidth(char) for char in string] )

text = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blablah"
limit = 60
words = text.split()
lines = [[]]
while( words ):
    word = words.pop(0)
    if stringwidth( " ".join(lines[-1]) ) + 1 + stringwidth(word) < limit:
        lines[-1].append(word)
    else:
        lines.append( [word] )

print( [" ".join(words) for words in lines ] )
```

Comment: This looks highly summarized. Taking it for a spin to ensure edge-cases don't break.

Comment: This is a good start, but doesn't break long words. One solution would be to replace the last "lines.append( [word] )" with a function that splits the lines until it fits. A simple brute-force solution would be to keep trying to add a substring of the word until it fits.

Comment: @Agargara The idea is just that, _not to break words_, but the lines. Breaking words would require hyphenation and I think that would require dictionarys and language-specific rules, so much more complex.

Comment: @Agargara @handle To add my own two cents here, breaking word might be inevitable as a *fallback* (as a secondary requirement, in cases where break sentence fails). This is for edge cases where users enter text that includes words greater in width than the base_image width. E.g. `I am soooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo happy to see you`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of @handle's third answer that also allows splitting long words.

This function also allows one to specify a maximum number of lines and truncate with "..." when over the limit.

```
def text_width(text, font):
    return font.getsize(text)[0]

# Set max_lines to 0 for no limit
def wrap_text(text, font, max_width, max_lines=0):
    words = text.split()
    lines = []
    while(words):
        word = words.pop(0)
        # Append word if it's not too long
        if len(lines) > 0 and (text_width(" ".join(lines[-1]), font) + 1 + text_width(word,font)) < max_width:
            lines[-1].append(word)
        else:
            # Brute-force: chunkify word until it fits
            chunk = len(word)
            while chunk > 0:
                while (text_width(word[:chunk],font) > max_width and chunk > 1):
                    chunk -= 1
                lines.append( [word[:chunk]] )
                word = word[chunk:]
                chunk = len(word)
    lines = [" ".join(words) for words in lines]
    if max_lines and len(lines) > max_lines:
        lines[max_lines-1] = lines[max_lines-1][:-1] + "..."
    return "\n".join(lines[:max_lines])
```